# Using BibTex with the Gummi editor

Tags: bibtex, gummi

I recently moved from Windows to Kubuntu and now I'm trying to get my Latex documents to compile. I use the Gummi editor, which seems nice (having realtime compilation).

But I can't get BibTex working. I have some citations, using `\cite{key}`, and at the bottom I have `\bibliography{References/references}`, where I have made sure that this is the right path starting from where the `.tex`-documents are saved (I have tried putting the full path, including `.bib` etc with the same results).

However all the references show up as `?`, and there is no bibliography at the bottom.

When I started running Gummi there was an option `Run BibTex` under `Document`, and I tried this. This didn't fix the references, even after compiling normally a few times.

But after I had clicked `Run BibTex` once it was greyed out and now I can no longer click it. This persists even when I change the citations or the `.bib`-file. I am used to having to run BibTex twice, but now I can't even run it once..

EDIT: When running from the command line it works. I run

```
pdflatex doc.tex
bibtex doc.aux
pdflatex doc.tex
pdflatex doc.tex
```

Then the resulting pdf has the citations.

Comment: Can you try running `bibtex` and `latex` from the command line? Then you can see if its a problem with the editor or the document.

Comment: Good idea; that does work (I'll edit the question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above the live preview in Gummi there are tabs named Preview Pane, Build Log, Project, and Bibliography. Click the Bibliography tab. Hit Detect, and references.bib should show up under Filename, with the message "references.bib loaded". Then press Compile. Hopefully that will produce the message "Bibliography complied without errors". Then compile the document twice, and all the references should show up as expected.