# On bibliography compilation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using Gummi on Raspbian, and am trying to get a bibliography file to compile. I've tried a number of tricks already mentioned on this site, to no avail.

The bibliography file is detected OK and lists my references OK (so I assume the .bib file is syntactically correct) but it won't compile.

The error that appears is:

```
I couldn't open database file .Thesis.tex-blx.bib
---line 3 of file /tmp/.Thesis.tex.aux
: \bibdata{.Thesis.tex-blx
:              ,/home/myusername/LaTeX/thesis}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file /
tmp/.Thesis.tex.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "biblatex-control"
Biblatex version: 1.7
```

Other relevant code:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric]{biblatex}
%other preamble stuff
\bibliography{thesis}
%body of my document
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Both my LaTeX file and .bib file are called "thesis", the former with a capital 'T'.

This is the first time I've ever had to make a bibliography (yay, mathematics courses!) so I've probably missed something incredibly obvious. Still, any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: You seem to be specifying the bibliography file (location) incorrectly.

Comment: Surely that's not it, if Gummi can correctly detect the file?

Comment: If your file is called `Thesis.tex`, BibTeX (which you seem to be using) needs to find `Thesis.aux`, not `Thesis.tex.aux`. It looks like something is confused about the appropriate file names involved. I wouldn't say that 'bibliography file is detected OK' here; why do you think it is?

Comment: Under the Bibliography tab, there is a button marked "Detect". When clicked, the right-hand pane correctly lists my references, in order.

Comment: Well `Detect` sounds good indeed (but what is doing the detecting?); however it does not seem that 'Gummi' is finding it. (What is Gummi, exactly? I thought it was a automated compilation process.)

Comment: Gummi is my LaTeX editor of choice.

Comment: And what is the complete name of your `.tex` file and bibliography file?  The error snippet you posted has very strange file names.  And, if you are using BibTeX, how are you calling your bibliography stuff in the `.tex` file?

Comment: I thought I put that information in the original post, but it appears to have disappeared... I'll patch that up within an hour, bear with me.

Comment: OK, now why is the error saying all the files in question are in a folder called `tmp` and then begin with a period (e.g., `.Thesis`)? When `latex` processes the file, it creates a new filed called (here) `Thesis.aux`; BibTeX needs to process that file (command: `bibtex Thesis.aux` or `bibtex Thesis`); this writes a file called `Thesis.bbl`, which is used by LaTeX on subsequent runs.  If you look at your errors, it keeps talking about files starting with `.Thesis`.  Also (unrelated to problem), nowadays you want to use `\addbibresource{thesis.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{thesis}`.

Comment: The messages make me think your editor is not properly configured to call BibTeX. It seems to call `bibtex .<basename>.tex` while the correct call would be `bibtex <basename>` or `bibtex <basename>.aux`. (See also [Using BibTex with the Gummi editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222892/35864), [How do I use biblatex with Gummi?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207464/35864))

Comment: Following the advice in another thread, I compiled my code with the commands `pdflatex` and `bibtex` - this time the code compiled quite fine. So I guess the question is now how to set up Gummi to properly use Bibtex - should I make this a new question?

Comment: You can simply update your question, I think. Since I don't use Gummi, could you provide screenshots of your current configuration? Is there are tab to configure the commands run by Gummi?